# How to label and cross-reference an equation by an actual name

Tags: equations, cross-referencing

I would like to label and cross-reference an equation not just by a number but by its name. I am looking for a simpler command than what I did by hand here:

```latex
\begin{align}
f: \mathbb{R}^{n} &\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m}\quad \textbf{Some Equation}\\
\label{eqn:someequation}
\end{align}
According to \textbf{Some equation} \eqref{eqn:someequation}
```

In this example, I have to write `\textbf{Some equation}` by hand two times but the name should be included in the `\label` and `\eqref` command.

Do you have an idea for that?

Answer (score 4):

Is this you looking for?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsfonts,mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
f: \mathbb{R}^{n} &\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m}
\tag*{\textbf{some equation}}\label{eq:someequation}
\end{align}
According to \ref{eq:someequation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great! But do you have a handy command for that? Maybe mathtools provides one command for ```\tag*{\textbf{some equation}}\label{eq:someequation}```?

Comment: It means, you want to migrate both tags (`\tag*` and `\label`) into a single tag? Am I correct?

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\nameandlabel}[3][\quad]{%
  #1% some space, \quad default
  \textnormal{\textbf{#2}}%
  {\def\@currentlabel{#2}\ltx@label{eqname@#3}}%
  \label{#3}%
}
\newcommand{\nameandref}[1]{%
  \textbf{\ref{eqname@#1}}~\eqref{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
f: \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m}
\nameandlabel{Some equation}{eqn:someequation}
\end{equation}

\begin{align}
a&=b     &&\nameandlabel[]{Main}{a=b} \\
c&=ddddd &&\nameandlabel[]{Useless}{c=d}
\end{align}
According to \nameandref{eqn:someequation}, \nameandref{a=b} and \nameandref{c=d}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For the `align` case you may want to use `alignat`.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \tag* macro
\newcommand{\mytag}[2]{%
   \refstepcounter{equation}
   \tag*{(\theequation\ -- #1)} % <-- adjust this line as needed
   \label{#2}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
a^2+b^2=c^2 \mytag{Pythagoras}{eq:pyth}
\end{equation}
According to equation \ref{eq:pyth}, \dots 

\end{document}
```